# NodeJS Firebase ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Upon trying to deploy index.js I get the following error in console:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/c3/fnyhf3gzz472z6fp_80gn/T/fbfn_12024O1uxG/index.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:32:3)
```

My code in index.js is the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require('./DERPTYDERP-DERP123abc-firebase-adminsdk-1o2i3u4y5t.json');
firebase.initializeApp({
   credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "https://derptyderpt-123abc.firebaseio.com/"
});

firebase.database().ref().once('value',function(snapshot){
    let something = snapshot.val();

  });
```

Comment: you error because not name function triggers

Answer (score 1):

You try to change this. if you need deploy cloud functions

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
//Name Triggers testData 
exports.testData = functions.database.ref('/data/{pushId}').onWrite(event => 
{
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const original = event.data.val();

});
```

> **Reference:** [Cloud Functions Trigger a database function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clearify how @aofdev's comment resolved my issue, I had written the code for a function say functionA and it's triggering route was say `/users/quotes{quoteId}` but then copied this function down when I wanted to create a new function say functionB. Changed the body implementation of the function and the function name without still not changing the triggering route. So now I have two functions with same triggering route and only one function( FunctionA) actually exported but then, when I deploy and wanted to trigger my function( FunctionA) for testing, I get the `ReferenceError` due to functionB being executed even though it was exported.
Check to ensure that this function is exported at the level of your index.js/ts file and doesn't have the same trigger route as another function in your functions project.

Hope this helps.